# When querying Amazon services with Zend (Zend_Service_Amazon), how to sort results by date?

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I have begun using Zend with PHP to run product searches against Amazon. However, I can't figure out how to sort the products by date -- since I want to find the most recent products which match my keywords. [The Amazon documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEcommerceService/2005-10-05/ApiReference/ItemSearchOperation.html) doesn't have much information on how to sort results. Here's my code:

```
$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon('AMAZON_API_KEY', 'US', 'AMAZON_SECRET_KEY');
$results = $amazon->itemSearch(array('SearchIndex' => 'Books',
                                     'Keywords' => 'Cooking'
));
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->Title . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried using the `Sort` parameter?

Parameter values may be found here - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEcommerceService/2006-11-14/ApiReference/SortValuesArticle.html

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, the documentation does mention the sort parameter but didn't give any information about what kind of strings to use as a sort string. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jason I noticed that. Had to Google "Amazon itemSearch sort"